# 1 and print gives different output in awk why?

Tags: awk

```
$ cat file
banana = yellow
strawberry = red

$ awk -F= '{print $2}' file
 yellow
 red

$ awk -F= '{$2}1' file
banana = yellow
strawberry = red
```

Comment: You should really add more detail and properly format your examples.

Comment: `1` causes the whole line to be printed.  It is short for `1 {print $0}`.   That is not the same as just printing the second field as you did with `print $2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F= '{print $2}' file
```

This prints the second column of each line of `file`. In this case, it will print:

```
 yellow
 red
```

(Note the leading whitespace because the separator was set to `=`).

This:

```
awk -F= '{$2}1' file
```

Is the same as:

```
awk -F= '1' file
```

Because the action `{ $2 }` doesn't have any effect: it doesn't print, it doesn't change any variable, nothing, it simply evaluates the value of `$2`. So it's useless. Thus the program is equivalent to `'1'` which is a pattern that always evaluates true. Since the default action for a pattern is to print the line, this is just printing the file. It's equivalent to:

```
awk -F= '{ print }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps for the second alternative you meant

```
awk -F= '{$0=$2}1'
```

otherwise $2 itself doesn't do anything.  Here 1 forces printing the line which is now set to field 2.